# How will Access a public Facebook profile in UIWebView

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cookies, uiwebview

How can one load Facebook URLs (such as Facebook Mobile ) as the already-authenticated user?

Using the Facebook SDK and already signed-in with SSO, when I try to load a facebook URL in a UIwebView I get a "You must log in first".. I'm guessing due to different cookies from the actual Safari browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Firstly you need to authenticate with facebook using graph api for example below. set authentication always use "FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView"

```
- (IBAction)clkFacebook:(id)sender {
    if (![SmashboardAPI hasInternetConnection]) {
        [AppDelegate showAlert:@"Error" message:@"Please check your internet connection."];
    } else {
        //[self disabledAllSocialButtons];
        [self showSpinner];
        // If the session state is any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
        if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
            || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {

            // Close the session and remove the access token from the cache
            // The session state handler (in the app delegate) will be called automatically
            // If the session state is not any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
        }
        else
        {

            FBSession* sess = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"public_profile",@"user_friends",@"email",nil]];

            [FBSession setActiveSession:sess];
            [sess openWithBehavior:(FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView) completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
             {
                 [appDel sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];

                 [self showSpinner];
                 [self getLoggedFBUserDetails];
             }];
        }
    }
}
```

//   Then use this method in Appdelegate.m so, that you can access from any where in your application.

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error
{
    // If the session was opened successfully
    if (!error && state == FBSessionStateOpen){
        // NSLog(@"Session opened");
        // Show the user the logged-in UI
        self.fbSession = FBSession.activeSession;
        //[self userLoggedIn];
        return;
    }
    if (state == FBSessionStateClosed || state == FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed) {
        // If the session is closed
        // NSLog(@"Session closed");
        // Show the user the logged-out UI
        [self userLoggedOut];
        return;
    }

    // Handle errors
    if (error){
        // NSLog(@"Error");
        NSString *alertText;
        NSString *alertTitle;
        // If the error requires people using an app to make an action outside of the app in order to recover
        if ([FBErrorUtility shouldNotifyUserForError:error] == YES){
            alertTitle = @"Something went wrong";
            alertText = [FBErrorUtility userMessageForError:error];
            [self showMessage:alertText withTitle:alertTitle];
        } else {

            // If the user cancelled login, do nothing
            if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled) {
                //  NSLog(@"User cancelled login");

                // Handle session closures that happen outside of the app
            } else if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryAuthenticationReopenSession){
                alertTitle = @"Session Error";
                alertText = @"Your current session is no longer valid. Please log in again.";
                [self showMessage:alertText withTitle:alertTitle];

                // For simplicity, here we just show a generic message for all other errors
                // You can learn how to handle other errors using our guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
            } else {
                //Get more error information from the error
                NSDictionary *errorInformation = [[[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey"] objectForKey:@"body"] objectForKey:@"error"];

                // Show the user an error message
                alertTitle = @"Something went wrong";
                alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Please retry. \n\n If the problem persists contact us and mention this error code: %@", [errorInformation objectForKey:@"message"]];
                [self showMessage:alertText withTitle:alertTitle];
            }
        }
        // Clear this token
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        // Show the user the logged-out UI
        //[self userLoggedOut];
    }
}
```

//   To Get User Details User this Method:

```
- (void)getLoggedFBUserDetails
{
    if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
        || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {

        //use this active session
        [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"user info: %@", result]);

            } else {
                // Check out our error handling guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors/
                    [AppDelegate showAlert:@"Facebook internal error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Description:%@",[error localizedDescription]]];
                    [self hideSpinner];
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

//    For loading timeline in UIWebview Use Below method:

```
- (void)loadFacebookTimeline {
    NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=%@",facebookUserId];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl]];
    // Load URL in UIWebView
    [webview loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is not possible  as you have logged into FB in a UIWebView of that particular application  but it is not saving credentials in all future session, So, it uses only once and then next time when you reallocate an UIWEBVIEW in the same application, all previous session is gone and you have to authenticate the user to access Facebook Profile.

Comment: Thanks Vizllx. But my point is how "MyPad" Application(https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mypad-for-facebook-instagram/id412133981?mt=8) is handling this thing. Login with webview and showing profile page in webview.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to Change the behaviour as underneath, during authentication.

[FBSession setActiveSession:sess];
            [sess openWithBehavior:(FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView) completionHandler:^(FBSession session, FBSessionState state, NSError error)
             { }];

It will definately work.